# Operand should contain 1 column(s) WHERE IN HAVING

Tags: sql

I have a query where I am testing an 'IN' against a select.

I am getting an "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" error which I assume is because I am selecting more than 1 column in my 'IN' Select. I need the second column as part of my selector because I need to check it against a 'having' statement.

How can I make this work to get my desired effect?

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.ID, Title, URLSegment
FROM ListingCategory c
LEFT JOIN SiteTree_Live ON c.ID = SiteTree_Live.ID
JOIN ListingCategory_Listings lc
      ON c.ID = lc.ListingCategoryID
        WHERE lc.ListingID IN (
            SELECT Listing.ID,
( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(-45.0227996) ) * COS( RADIANS( Location.Latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( Location.Longitude ) - RADIANS(168.6991149) ) + SIN( RADIANS(-45.0227996) ) * SIN( RADIANS( Location.Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM Listing
LEFT JOIN Location ON Listing.LocationID = Location.ID
having distance < 5
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy - just don't select the calculated column. Also, it should be `WHERE`, not `HAVING`:

```
...
WHERE lc.ListingID IN (
    SELECT Listing.ID
    FROM Listing
    LEFT JOIN Location ON Listing.LocationID = Location.ID
    WHERE 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(-45.0227996) ) * COS( RADIANS( Location.Latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( Location.Longitude ) - RADIANS(168.6991149) ) + SIN( RADIANS(-45.0227996) ) * SIN( RADIANS( Location.Latitude ) ) )
        < 5
);
```

Comment: I love you and want to have your babies. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you you want to do cannot be done. An IN subquery must return a single column.

My suggestion is that you add table LINSTING to the join chain and then ask `Listing.ID is not null`.

Also: HAVING is for queries that have a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thanks for responding. When I run the subquery independent of the main query, it correctly brings back the results I am after

Comment: Sure, but when part of a `IN` clause, a subquery must return a single column, because you cannot compare a single column to several columns.  Basically an IN clause compares one column of the external query with one column of the internal one. SQL cannot compare and ID with both an ID and a distance.